# System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.'

Tags: c#, radtreeview

I am working on a project with RadTreeView.

I am trying to bind the Nodes with names coming from db.

Data binding is done when the remark panel is opened(when 'Remark' is clicked' so not in Page_Load because Page Load is just for opening the main page. If I am wrong please correct me.

However, I am getting the error:

**System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.'**

Please find my server and clients code as below.

.ascx

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
<script>

    function OpenEditWindow() {
        var appWindow = $find("<%=rdwRemark.ClientID%>");
        appWindow.show();
    }

    function CloseEditWindow() {
        var appWindow = $find("<%=rdwRemark.ClientID%>");
        appWindow.close();
    }
</script>

</telerik:RadScriptBlock>

<telerik:RadWindow ID="rdwRemark" runat="server" Title="Remark"
    Width="375" Height="400"
    Behaviors="Close"
    Modal="true"
    CenterIfModal="true"
    Skin="Telerik">

    <ContentTemplate>

        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel3" runat="server">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOrderId" runat="server" />

                        <telerik:RadTreeView RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTreeView1"
                            EnableDragAndDrop="false" 
                            OnClientNodeDropping="onDropping" EnableDragAndDropBetweenNodes="false">
                            <Nodes>

                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Alt Yuklenici" AllowDrag="false">

                                <NodeTemplate>

                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(SqlDataSource1 , "Name") %>

                                </NodeTemplate>

                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>

                            </Nodes>
                        </telerik:RadTreeView>   
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TTMS_DB %>"
                SelectCommand="Select [Name] from [TTMS].[P21].[P_Master_Subcontractors] "></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

.ascx.cs

```
    protected void grdOrder_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Remark")
        {
            RadTreeView1.DataBind(); //data bind is done when Remark is clicked.

            var orderval = (e.Item as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("ORDER_ID").ToString();
            var orderData = pmsSrv.GetOrderByOrderId(orderval.ToInt());
            //var textbox = RadAjaxPanel3.FindControl("textbox") as TextBox;
            //textbox.Text = orderData.Remark;
            (RadAjaxPanel3.FindControl("hdnOrderId") as HiddenField).Value = orderval;
            pmsSrv.ResponseScript("OpenEditWindow()");
            return;
        }
      }
```

Even 'Name' exists in the db the code cannot find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Kind Regards.

Comment: The thing is I would like to have the Names under 'Alt Yuklenici' so I am using Eval in RadTreeNode 'Alt Yuklenici'. How will I achieve this? Any help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [`DataBinder.Eval()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?view=netframework-4.7.2) used to evaluate data-binding expression from object container, such like `Container.DataItem`. Since [`SqlDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties)  doesn't have `Name` property, you can't use that for data binding with `RadTreeNode`.

Instead, you need to use `Container.DataItem` for data binding purpose:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
```

Also don't forget to bind `RadTreeView` to the data source by setting `DataSourceID`, `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` like example below:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTreeView1"
                     EnableDragAndDrop="false"
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                     DataTextField="Name" 
                     DataValueField="Name" 
                     OnClientNodeDropping="onDropping" EnableDragAndDropBetweenNodes="false">
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

References for further reading:

[RadTreeView - Binding to ASP.NET DataSource Components (Telerik Docs)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/treeview/data-binding/binding-to-asp.net-datasource-components)

[RadTreeView - Data Binding Overview (Telerik Docs)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/treeview/data-binding/overview)

Comment: The thing is I would like to have the Names under 'Alt Yuklenici' parent so I am using Eval in RadTreeNode 'Alt Yuklenici'. With your approach yes the names are listed but not under 'Alt Yuklenici' so as seperate. How will i achieve this? Thanks much.